How to calculate non systematic ADC error in perfect scenario
I'm using the ADC "ADC121C021" (datasheet) in my design. My question is rather theoretical.
Given a perfect (noise free) reference voltage and input voltage, is it possible to calculate the probable non-systematic error of the measurement from the datasheet?
For example, when I want to measure 1 V at the input (which corresponds to a digital value of 1000, given a reference voltage of 4.096 V) and I perform 100 consecutive measurements. How much will the measured digital value vary because of intrinsic effects of the ADC?

For an ideal 1V input voltage and 4.096V reference, the measurement will be within the specs given in the data sheet.
For an ideal ADC, the measurement would be exactly 1000.0, and and any voltage between values 999.5 and 1000.5 would round to an integer result of 1000.
But, the ADC is not ideal. Over full temperature and supply voltage range and with some specified sampling rate, the INL error is typically +/-1 counts, DNL is typically within +/- 1 counts, offset error within +/- 1.6 counts and gain error +/- 6 counts.
So in light of this, even worst case, I would expect the result to be within 10 counts of the ideal. And since it is possible that the errors cause the 1V input to be right between two different conversion results, it might alternate between two different values.
The data sheet has graphs with more specific values how the typical errors behave based on supply voltage, temperature and sampling rate.
So for 100 samples taken, all samples might be equal but something else than 1000 as it will have some DC bias error like 1005. It may also be that all samples are not equal and may vary between 2 (or 3) different values, like 1005 and 1006.
The error can vary because the circuit is at room temperature when you start it and then the chip warms up (by itself or due to other nearby components) and it changes the error.

So the results of the conversions should all have the same value but are most likely different from the ideal value of 1000, right? So there is no instrinsic "noise" from the adc that could result in an error of about ±1 LSB?

@Robert I think I just said the opposite. Everything in real world has noise and you may encounter that the result may be right at the edge of two values and depending on that noise it may jump between two values.

Right, but there is no value in the datasheet that indicates the "amount of noise" that comes from the adc which is resulting in jumping values? I know that in the real world all there are many different noise sources to consider but i wanted to start with the adc to evaluate the maximum possible error between measurements.

@Robert I just said there is. For your given chip, the manufacturing tolerances, usage temperature and voltage will lead to the error to drift and at some point it will be X+0.5, so the 1.000V is right halfway between e.g. 1005 and 1006. Basically it might be either and in practice it will wiggle between the two as there is always uncertainty around that point, even from internal structues of the analog input, such as thermal or switching noise of the analog input structure before the sampled signal is converted by the "ideal" ADC.

Ah ok. Thanks a lot!
